# How to develop a graph visual editor in javascript?

Tags: javascript, web, drag-and-drop, editor, visual-programming

I need to develop something similar to this : http://draw.io
It needs to include :

- a main canvas
- toolbars
- **drag'n drop** elements from toolbar to canvas
- link nodes with edges ...

Where to start ? What API or framework should one use ?

Comment: ....why not look at their [Github](https://github.com/jgraph/draw.io)?

Comment: Thanks ! I'll try to figure out how it works

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://fabricjs.com/ i have used it with great success to make things like that. It will be no small project thou.

Comment: Thaks for your help !